# Vector of shared_ptr resulting in error: "no instance of overloaded function" when wanting to push_back vector list

Tags: c++, vector, shared-ptr, derived-class

I have a smart pointer of a base class to prevent object slicing like so:

```
vector<shared_ptr<BaseClass>> vectorOfObjects;
```

I want to pass this object through a function and then add a derived object to the vector list:

```
function(vector<shared_ptr<BaseClass>>& vectorOfObjects) {}
```

In this function, I create a new derived object that I want to add to the list:

```
DerivedClass derivedObject = DerivedClass();

vectorOfObjects.push_back(&derivedObject);
```

I'm getting an error under the dot of the last line above stating

```
no instance of overloaded function std::vector<_Ty,_Ax>::pushback
 [with _Ty="std::tr1::shared_ptr<BaseClass>,_Ax=std::allocator<std:
:tr1::shared_ptr<BaseClass>>]" matches the argument list
```

Any help at all would be much appreciated as I can't seem to find the right solution to pass a vector consisting of a pointer of objects (required to prevent object slicing) through a function.

Comment: That's not how shared pointers work. They share ownership of a *dynamically allocated* object.

Comment: @KerrekSB I've seen online recommendations to avoid the use of raw pointers due to fiddly memory management and so this was the alternative as a smart pointer.

Comment: The problem with C++ is that there isn't a simple recipe book that you can follow blindly. There are lots of good tools, but you still need to understand what they're for and when to use what. Most likely you don't want any additional dynamic allocation and shared ownership at all, but it's of course impossible to tell without context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
// DerivedClass derivedObject = DerivedClass(); <<< Not needed
vectorOfObjects.push_back(std::make_shared<DerivedClass>());
```

There's a number of [constructor declarations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr) that allow conversion from a `std::shared_ptr<DerivedClass>` to `std::shared_ptr<BaseClass>`.

---

As from your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36825466/vector-of-shared-ptr-resulting-in-error-no-instance-of-overloaded-function-wh/36825584?noredirect=1#comment61222614_36825584)

> If I need to make a separate declaration, as I also have a vector member in my BaseClass, how can I declare a derivedObject separately as I have attempted earlier?

It's not completely clear for me what *"as I also have a vector member in my BaseClass"* has to do with it, but if you insist you can do:

```
DerivedClass derivedObject* = new DerivedClass();
// Do special stuff only available in DerivedClass
derivedObject->specialFunc();
vectorOfObjects.push_back(std::shared_ptr<DerivedClass>(derivedObject));
```

Comment: What if I want to add the overloaded constructor object of the derived class to the vector rather than the default constructor?
Say, `DerivedClass derivedObject = DerivedClass(x, y);`

Comment: @MoB [std::make_shared](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) allows to pass an arbitrary number of constructor parameters.

Comment: Ahh of course, thank you very much for the help! It's greatly appreciated!

Comment: If I need to make a separate declaration, as I also have a vector member in my BaseClass, how can I declare a derivedObject separately as I have attempted earlier?

Comment: Have managed to solve my previous comment by accessing `vectorOfObjects[1]->functionInBaseClassToAddArgumentToVectorInClass(argument)`

  Thank you once again, now I just have to tidy up the access to the classes as [1] was just to test my class!

Comment: @MoB You should probably better use something like: `vectorOfObjects.back()-> ...`.

Comment: Thank you so much once again, that's even tidier!  I'm relatively new to object oriented programming and inheritance of classes and you have greatly helped me solve the syntax issues! :)